# Is there something like [aCalCalendar setType] in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, types, calendar, cloud

Can I generate a new `CalCalendar` in my Cocoa program, that uses (for example) Google? In other words, can I *set* the type of the `CalCalendar` object? I know I can read it, but there seems to be no such thing as [aCalCalendar setType] method....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Under "[Creating Calendars](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/CalendarStoreProgGuide/Articles/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005158-DontLinkElementID_5)", the documentation states that:

> You create a calendar object using the `calendar` class method of `CalCalendar`. Optionally, you can then set the color, notes, or title properties.
>   **Currently, you can create iCal calendars only**.

As you allude to in your question, the `type` property of a `CalCalendar` object is defined as read-only, which means you're out of luck at present.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that. Is there some backward way of generating google calendars from a cocoa program that someone has tried before? Perhaps it would be possible with applescript or some such thing. For my program, I need to check for, and possibly make, several cloud based calendars...

Comment: Maybe not really a Cocoa question, but it might be worth trying to set up an iCal calendar on an OSX server, and then share the calendar with the users of choice... Unless someone beats me to it, I will post my findings after I tried this.

Comment: It will be possible to do this kind of thing in the new EventKit, which will supersede CalCalendar!